# hero image is not showing up

Tags: html, css, w3-css

I am working on a website and i'm trying to get an image to display across the full top of the page basically like a banner, i am attempting to do this using the hero image however would be open to other suggestions that may work better for me. problem i am having is that no matter what i do the image does not show up, if i add text the text just shows where the image would be but no image exists. looked at the console and the path is correct and no errors show up there. I am also using w3.css for my main stylesheet

here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Home</TITLE>
        <META name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../resources/w3.css">
    </HEAD>
    <STYLE>
        body,html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .custom-background {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: darkgreen;
        }
        .hero-image {
            background-image: url("../images/banner.jpg");
            height: 20%;
            width: 100%;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative;
        }

    </STYLE>
    <BODY>
        <a href = "home.html">
            <div clas = "hero-image"></div>
        </a>
        <div class = "w3-bar custom-background">
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "home.html">Home</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "aboutus.html">About Us</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "salonservices.html">Salon Services</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "jobs.php">Apply Here</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "shopaveda.html">Shop Aveda</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "contact.php">Contact Us</a></div>
            <div class = "w3-bar-item w3-mobile"><a href = "policies.html">Policies</a></div>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am trying to get the "banner" to go across the entirety of the screen just like the navigation bar does.

Comment: Typo `<div clas` should be `<div class='hero-image'>`?

Comment: @scrappedcola jesus...thanks i've been looking at this for hours and couldn't find it, now i feel stupid

Comment: We've all been there...

Comment: @tgrim90 np it happens a lot. What I try to do to double check I haven't done something silly like this is to inspect the element and double check I see the applied style first. If I don't see it then I start looking to see if everything is spelled correctly. This can also catch if you accidentally miss a `;` in your css file.